# Count items in SQL Table

Tags: sql, select, mysqli

I need to write a query that will print the respective Department name and number of employees for all departments given these two tables, and be in descending order.

```
Employee 
---------------
ID        Integer
NAME      String
SALARY    Integer
DEPT_ID   Integer

Department
---------------
DEPT_ID     Integer
NAME        String
LOCATION    String
```

Comment: try with group by clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could group by `department.name` and apply `count(*)` to each group:

```
SELECT   d.name, COUNT(*)
FROM     department d
JOIN     employee e ON d.dept_id = e.dept_id
GROUP BY d.name
ORDER BY 2 ASC, 1 ASC
```

Comment: if two departments have the same amount of employees, how can I sort alphabetically by name?

Comment: `ORDER BY 2 ASC, d.name ASC`

Comment: @ralphie9224 You can add another term to the `order by` clause - see my edited answer.

Comment: Good answer, though, may be a better practice to define aliases and use them instead of indexes, in general.